# geom_segment produces errant arrow when using facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I prevent that errant arrow from appearing?

```
x<-seq(-2,2,by=0.1)
df<-rbind(data.frame(x,y=sin(x),type="sin"),data.frame(x,y=cos(x),type="cos"))
ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+
geom_point()+
facet_grid(. ~ type)+
geom_segment(aes(xend=c(tail(x, n=-1), NA), yend=c(tail(y, n=-1), NA)),arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.2,"cm")))
```

[image]

R 3.3.2

ggplot2_2.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are only inserting one `NA` into your `xend` and `yend`. This works:

```
xx=seq(-2, 2, 0.1)
df<-rbind(data.frame(x=xx,y=sin(xx),type="sin"),data.frame(x=xx,y=cos(xx),type="cos"))
ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_grid(. ~ type)+
  geom_segment(aes(xend=rep(c(tail(xx, n=-1), NA), 2), yend=c(tail(y, n=-1), NA)),arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.2,"cm")))
```